# can we use a function while accepting parameters in oracle procedure

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, syntax

I need to ensure that the parameter "lastname" that is being passed to my Oracle procedure is in "initcap" format. Can I use the INITCAP function while accepting the value itself?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_SPRIDEN_7_INSERT
 (
 PIDM in varchar2,
 STUD_ID IN OUT VARCHAR2,
 INITCAP(LASTNAME) IN VARCHAR2,
 ERROR OUT VARCHAR2
)
```

Comment: You could test the value within the procedure and throw an exception; or convert whatever you are given - depends whether you're being strict or helpful I suppose. But names don't always start with an uppercase character... how would you store Cyrano de Bergerac, or Lars von Trier, or.. er... ee cummings, as a few feeble examples? Or Edward d'Eath? There are various lists of myths about names floating about on the internet.

Comment: Hi Alex, Yes there are all kinds of names and it may be impossible to have a common case rule for all of them. But for now this is what the customer wants. Guess I will have to accept the parameter as is and inside the procedure assign the initcap value of the input parameter to a variable and use that variable instead of the input parameter in the code.

Comment: Yes, as long as you want to accept and convert anything; it wasn't clear from your question whether you might actually want to reject anything that isn't already in init-caps.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a procedure like this. The easiest way to get this behavior is to explicitly call `initcap` on that argument before using it in the procedure's body.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The procedure is called from a ETL software and I don't know any function there to apply while calling the procedure. I might have to  accept the parameter as is and inside the procedure assign the initcap value of the input parameter to a variable and use that variable instead of the input parameter in the code.